# Problem with convex differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be convex and differentiable function. Prove that
$$(\forall x \in(a,b))  f(x)=\max_{t\in (a,b)}(f(t)+f'(t)(x-t))$$
Hint is to apply Lagrange theorem and fact that first derivative of convex function increases, but I don't know how to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x, y \in (a, b)$, convex, differentiable functions always fulfil:
$$
f(x)\geq f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)
$$
So $\displaystyle \max_{t \in (a, b)} f(t)+f'(t)(x-t) \leq \max_{t \in (a, b)} f(x) = f(x)$
Also, trivially
$$
\max_{t \in (a, b)} f(t)+f'(t)(x-t) \geq f(x)+f'(x)(x-x) = f(x).
$$

So how is the very first inequality proved? Let $f$ be convex differentiable. By definition, it fulfils for all $\lambda \in (0, 1)$:
$$
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y) \iff \frac{f(y+\lambda(x-y))-f(y)}{\lambda} \leq f(x)-f(y).
$$
As $\lambda \downarrow 0$, the L.H.S. does the following: (we use Taylor in $\lambda = 0$)
$$
\lim_{\lambda\downarrow 0} \frac{f(y+\lambda(x-y))-f(y)}{\lambda} = \lim_{\lambda\downarrow 0} \frac{\lambda f'(y)(x-y) + o(\lambda)}{\lambda} = f'(y)(y-x)
$$
So as $\lambda \downarrow 0$:
$$
f'(y)(y-x)\leq f(x) - f(y)
$$

Comment: Meowdog how do I prove that convex functions fulfill such an inequality?

Comment: I'll ad something

Comment: Meowdog Also do you have any idea what will be the geometric interpretation of this problem (equality)?

Comment: $x\mapsto f(t)+f'(t)(x-t)$ is the tangent line at $f(t)$. So, if we evaluate it at $x$, the tangent line that has the highest value at $x$ is the one that belongs to $f(x)$. Just draw it and you will see.

Comment: I understand, thank you.